# Elapsed time crystal formula

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm looking to have elapsed time on a report and I'm using this but it does not work– any other suggestions?

If not isnull({table1.end_time}) and not isnull({table1.start_time}) then
TimeValue({table1.end_time}) - TimeValue({table1.start_time})

I also tried this

If not isnull({table1.end_time}) and not isnull({table1.start_time}) then
Minute({table1.end_time}) - Minute({table1.start_time})

Do I need a conversion of time first?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [ElapsedTime](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/29/crystal-reports-elapsedtime-function/) function that I wrote.